# Using 2d arrays to store strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, multidimensional-array

I want to make a program that handles strings in 2d arrays in the following manner:

Each row represents one name only, while columns holds separate characters of each name.

Like so:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 K e v i n \0
1 J o h n \0
2 L u c y \0
```

Now, the way I understand arrays is that they work as pointers for the first element. So when I read the string using the readstring(name) function even though I used a 1D array, it should work as a pointer to the 2D array and store each string as I showed above, right?

The following code is supposed to ask for three names then print them all, but it only prints the last name and some gibberish, what did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readstring(char name[]);
void get_data(char name[][15]);
void show_data(char name[][15]);

int main()
{
    char name[3][15];

    get_data(name);
    show_data(name);

    return 0;
}

void get_data(char name[][15]){
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            printf("\nEnter name: ");
            readstring(name);
        }
}

void show_data(char name[][15]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%s",name[i]);
    }

}

void readstring(char str[]){
    int i=0;
    while((str[i++]=getchar())!='\n' && i<15);
    str[i]='\0';

}
```

The output shows like this:

http://i58.tinypic.com/e7i048.jpg

Comment: Pay attention to compiler warnings. They would show you exactly where the problem is here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
readstring(name);
```

Change it to:

```
readstring(name[i]);
```

The problem is that `name` is a 2 - d array, or , an array of strings. Therefore, to access one string in the array of strings, you need to use an index for that particular string.

In fact, the calling function `readstring()` expects a string as an argument.

Comment: "*not an array of strings*" is not right as `name`, in `get_data` is not a 2D array. It is a pointer to an array of 15 `char`s in `get_data`.

Comment: Oh! Took me some time to understand why it works now, but thanks!

Comment: @CoolGuy: Thanks! I missed that.